# Array holds 9 Elements but out of range?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting this error, even though my code behind is set to handle the proper number of parameters.  C# uses a 0 based array, and I have only 9 elements in my array, so what is out of range?

Here is my call:

```
let allvalues = employeefirstname & "," & employeelastname & "," & Convert.ToString(userID) & "," & JobSite & "," & abcd & "," & efg & "," & Convert.ToString(habib) & "," & ToString(alpha) & "," & departurereason & "," & ToString(departuredate)
```

Then here is my call:

> "http://yourwebsiteinformationhere.aspx?passedin="&allvalues

and my code behind:

```
try {
        string Info = Request["allvalues"];
        string[] spl = Info.Split(',');
        //Generate SMPT email here
        msg.Body = spl[1] + " " + spl[2] + " " + spl[3]+ " " + spl[4] + " " + spl[5]+ " " + spl[6]+ " " + spl[7]+ " " + spl[8]+ " " + spl[9]
//send mail here
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
   throw exception;
}
```

Comment: You've mentioned correctly that C# uses zero-based indexes. But in your code you have 1-based index.

Comment: I sure hope jobsite never has a comma in it...

Comment: And I count 10 elements, not 9.

Comment: @sstan -- their are 10 elements but since it is 0 based it's 9.

Comment: @Simon: That's confusing.  You should say you have 10 elements going from indexes 0 to 9.  But saying you have 9 elements is not true.

Comment: @sstan - I follow your logic now.  Sorry for the mishap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays in C# are zero-based, so they go from 0 to Count-1 (8 in your case):

```
msg.Body = spl[0] + " " + spl[1] + " " + spl[2] + " " + spl[3]+ " " + spl[4] + " " + spl[5]+ " " + spl[6]+ " " + spl[7]+ " " + spl[8]+ " ";
```

*However* a safer method that does not rely on array size is to use [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx):

```
msg.Body = string.Join(" ", spl);
```

Plus you are pulling the wrong query string as @sstan noted.

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
Request["passedin"];
```

not:

```
Request["allvalues"];
```